# ZeroMQ Receive-Status Interrupted when compiled in Release

Tags: .net, release, zeromq

we're testing with ZeroMQ unter VB.NET and have a strange effect when using PUB/SUB Sockets. When we compile in Debug-Mode, everything works well. When in Release, the SUB-Programm gets an socket.Receivestatus=Interrupted. Code-Snippet:

```
    Dim context = ZmqContext.Create
    Dim socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.SUB)
    socket.SubscribeAll()
    socket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5550")
    socket.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)
    socket.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...")
    While True
        Dim msg As String
        msg = socket.Receive(Encoding.Unicode)
        Select Case socket.ReceiveStatus
            Case ReceiveStatus.Interrupted
                Console.WriteLine("Status={0}", socket.ReceiveStatus)
....
```

As far we can see it right now, it has to do with the length of each message; if it is small (<100 bytes) everything works in Debug & Release-Mode. If we go up to let's say 2000 bytes per Message, only 137 messages are received and then the error occurs.

We installed ZeroMQ via NuGet (package id="clrzmq" version="3.0.0-rc1"). We checked 32bit and 64bit - same behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it out: you have to turn off the "Optimization"-Checkbox under Project-Settings...Compile...Advanced Options. After that change, everything worked fine.

My advise: Behaviour be fixed in a future version of ZeroMQ, as if someone forgets to disable this option, a system will work under Test (Debug)-Conditions but fail in Live (Release).